# How to directly access remote database hosted on windows server which is accessible by IIS of that same server but not accessible from outside

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, remote-access

How to directly access remote database hosted on windows server which is accessible by IIS of that same server. And the IIS is accessible from the outside but database is not accessible from the outside. We are able to access the database using API which is hosted on the IIS. Instead of using the API how we are able to access the database in our local application directly or via using the IIS of the server.

Comment: You would need to ask the owner of the database and discuss access with them. We can't tell you what security restrictions have been placed on that database...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a business problem, not a technical question.

Comment: It might be ok to ask this at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Its not a business problem I am asking for any possible way to access the remote database which is remotely added in the SQL server of the dev server.